# Why does my code break when I change the URL in the Tableau sample to another URL?

Tags: javascript, html, url, tableau-api

Why does my code break when I change the URL in the Tableau sample from
https://help.tableau.com/current/api/js_api/en-us/JavaScriptAPI/js_api_sample_basic_embed.htm
to the below URL?
https://public.tableau.com/profile/david.walls2745#!/vizhome/OlderWorkers_15998328862500/Dashboard1

ie. this works:

````
  ```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Basic Embed</title>
 <script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://public.tableau.com/javascripts/api/tableau-2.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">    
 function initViz(){var containerDiv = document.getElementById("vizContainer"),
 url = "http://public.tableau.com/views/RegionalSampleWorkbook/Storms",
 options = {hideTabs: true, onFirstInteractive: function(){console.log("Run this code when the
 viz has finished loading."); } }; var viz = new tableau.Viz(containerDiv, url, options);}
 </script>
</head>
<body onload="initViz();">
    <div id="vizContainer" style="width:800px; height:700px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
  ```
````

and this doesn't:

````
  ```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Basic Embed</title>
  <script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://public.tableau.com/javascripts/api/tableau-2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function initViz() {var containerDiv = document.getElementById("vizContainer"),
  url ="https://public.tableau.com/profile/david.walls2745#!/vizhome/OlderWorkers_15998328862500/Dashboard1",
  options = { hideTabs: true, onFirstInteractive:function(){console.log("Run this code when 
  the viz has finished loading."); } };var viz = new tableau.Viz(containerDiv, url, options);}
  </script>
</head>
<body onload="initViz();">
    <div id="vizContainer" style="width:800px; height:700px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
  ```
````

Comment: Where are you placing this html block?

Comment: C: drive on on my laptop. The first html block opens in any browser without hassles.

Comment: The only change in the code is the URL from http://public.tableau.com/views/RegionalSampleWorkbook/Storms to https://public.tableau.com/profile/david.walls2745#!/vizhome/OlderWorkers_15998328862500/Dashboard1

Comment: all rights are enabled on the new URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format for URLs you need when embedding is different than what you see in your browser's address bar. The URL you should use for that viz is `https://public.tableau.com/views/OlderWorkers_15998328862500/Dashboard1`. You can get this URL by copying the link from the Share button.

[image]